# How do I select an expandable item in selenium

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select an element on a webpage with selenium and am having no success. It is an expandable item that makes other items/fields visible when clicked.

Code for element:

```
<DIV class="section">
    <H1 class="sectionHeader collapsed" onclick="toggleSection('ResolutionSection',this,'YES')">Resolution Section</H1>
        <span style="width:100%;text-align: right;">
            <A HREF="#top" class="toplink">
                Go to top
            </A>
```

Selenium Code I have tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[2]/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[1]/div[4]/h1")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='documentLayoutSection']/div[4]/h1")).click()
```

Errors I have gotten:

```
Jun 15, 2014 7:45:18 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

OR `cannot find element.`

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: on which line you are getting the error? Try putting an implicit wait

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use an `Actions` chain:

```
(new Actions(driver))
    .moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h1.sectionHeader.collapsed")))
    .click()
    .build()
    .perform();
```

The `onclick` javascript event may be changing the page in a way that makes the page difficult for Selenium to interact with.  After a `click`, Selenium expects to be able to interact with the element again.  If the element changes during the `onclick` javascript event, Selenium is not able to get a response back from the element after the `click`.

This makes Selenium very sad.

Since this `Actions` chain is built to click where the mouse currently is, it may work.

Failing that, I think we're going to need to see more HTML, or better yet, a link to the page if possible.

Comment: Thank you for the input, this might work, I tried with this method, but using By.xpath() because there are multiple of these elements on the page so by css selector isn't unique enough (I am still getting the element not found error). A little more info: I am using the ie driver (the page only functions on IE) I am also noticing that I am getting the cannot locate element error before the page even finishes loading.